# Pandas function for removing every other value based on other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm creating two dataframes where I store minimum and maximum time series values which index is based on datetime. The two Dataframes, one for maximas and one for minimas, should each have only 3 entries. The problem I'm having is that I don't want there to be two maximas/minimas in a row, so every maxima index should be followed by a minima index.

Here is what i got so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
df=pd.Series({Timestamp('2020-11-30 00:35:00'): '0.03119', Timestamp('2020-11-30 00:40:00'): '0.03116', Timestamp('2020-11-30 00:45:00'): '0.03118', Timestamp('2020-11-30 00:50:00'): '0.03123', Timestamp('2020-11-30 00:55:00'): '0.03124', Timestamp('2020-11-30 01:00:00'): '0.03115', Timestamp('2020-11-30 01:05:00'): '0.03123', Timestamp('2020-11-30 01:10:00'): '0.03147', Timestamp('2020-11-30 01:15:00'): '0.03131', Timestamp('2020-11-30 01:20:00'): '0.03119', Timestamp('2020-11-30 01:25:00'): '0.03117', Timestamp('2020-11-30 01:30:00'): '0.03115', Timestamp('2020-11-30 01:35:00'): '0.03122', Timestamp('2020-11-30 01:40:00'): '0.03126', Timestamp('2020-11-30 01:45:00'): '0.03135', Timestamp('2020-11-30 01:50:00'): '0.03133', Timestamp('2020-11-30 01:55:00'): '0.03125', Timestamp('2020-11-30 02:00:00'): '0.03120', Timestamp('2020-11-30 02:05:00'): '0.03115', Timestamp('2020-11-30 02:10:00'): '0.03115', Timestamp('2020-11-30 02:15:00'): '0.03115', Timestamp('2020-11-30 02:20:00'): '0.03115', Timestamp('2020-11-30 02:25:00'): '0.03112', Timestamp('2020-11-30 02:30:00'): '0.03113', Timestamp('2020-11-30 02:35:00'): '0.03114', Timestamp('2020-11-30 02:40:00'): '0.03121', Timestamp('2020-11-30 02:45:00'): '0.03122', Timestamp('2020-11-30 02:50:00'): '0.03123', Timestamp('2020-11-30 02:55:00'): '0.03123', Timestamp('2020-11-30 03:00:00'): '0.03116', Timestamp('2020-11-30 03:05:00'): '0.03102', Timestamp('2020-11-30 03:10:00'): '0.03105', Timestamp('2020-11-30 03:15:00'): '0.03113', Timestamp('2020-11-30 03:20:00'): '0.03126', Timestamp('2020-11-30 03:25:00'): '0.03137', Timestamp('2020-11-30 03:30:00'): '0.03140', Timestamp('2020-11-30 03:35:00'): '0.03142', Timestamp('2020-11-30 03:40:00'): '0.03136', Timestamp('2020-11-30 03:45:00'): '0.03142', Timestamp('2020-11-30 03:50:00'): '0.03127', Timestamp('2020-11-30 03:55:00'): '0.03134', Timestamp('2020-11-30 04:00:00'): '0.03122', Timestamp('2020-11-30 04:05:00'): '0.03119', Timestamp('2020-11-30 04:10:00'): '0.03113', Timestamp('2020-11-30 04:15:00'): '0.03105', Timestamp('2020-11-30 04:20:00'): '0.03104', Timestamp('2020-11-30 04:25:00'): '0.03111', Timestamp('2020-11-30 04:30:00'): '0.03110', Timestamp('2020-11-30 04:35:00'): '0.03105', Timestamp('2020-11-30 04:40:00'): '0.03112', Timestamp('2020-11-30 04:45:00'): '0.03100', Timestamp('2020-11-30 04:50:00'): '0.03104', Timestamp('2020-11-30 04:55:00'): '0.03108', Timestamp('2020-11-30 05:00:00'): '0.03108', Timestamp('2020-11-30 05:05:00'): '0.03115', Timestamp('2020-11-30 05:10:00'): '0.03115', Timestamp('2020-11-30 05:15:00'): '0.03113', Timestamp('2020-11-30 05:20:00'): '0.03116', Timestamp('2020-11-30 05:25:00'): '0.03132', Timestamp('2020-11-30 05:30:00'): '0.03127', Timestamp('2020-11-30 05:35:00'): '0.03124', Timestamp('2020-11-30 05:40:00'): '0.03118', Timestamp('2020-11-30 05:45:00'): '0.03111', Timestamp('2020-11-30 05:50:00'): '0.03108', Timestamp('2020-11-30 05:55:00'): '0.03108', Timestamp('2020-11-30 06:00:00'): '0.03109', Timestamp('2020-11-30 06:05:00'): '0.03108', Timestamp('2020-11-30 06:10:00'): '0.03114', Timestamp('2020-11-30 06:15:00'): '0.03117', Timestamp('2020-11-30 06:20:00'): '0.03103', Timestamp('2020-11-30 06:25:00'): '0.03097', Timestamp('2020-11-30 06:30:00'): '0.03098', Timestamp('2020-11-30 06:35:00'): '0.03101', Timestamp('2020-11-30 06:40:00'): '0.03103', Timestamp('2020-11-30 06:45:00'): '0.03109', Timestamp('2020-11-30 06:50:00'): '0.03108', Timestamp('2020-11-30 06:55:00'): '0.03110', Timestamp('2020-11-30 07:00:00'): '0.03111', Timestamp('2020-11-30 07:05:00'): '0.03119', Timestamp('2020-11-30 07:10:00'): '0.03130', Timestamp('2020-11-30 07:15:00'): '0.03126', Timestamp('2020-11-30 07:20:00'): '0.03130', Timestamp('2020-11-30 07:25:00'): '0.03133', Timestamp('2020-11-30 07:30:00'): '0.03128', Timestamp('2020-11-30 07:35:00'): '0.03120', Timestamp('2020-11-30 07:40:00'): '0.03115', Timestamp('2020-11-30 07:45:00'): '0.03118', Timestamp('2020-11-30 07:50:00'): '0.03113', Timestamp('2020-11-30 07:55:00'): '0.03109', Timestamp('2020-11-30 08:00:00'): '0.03079', Timestamp('2020-11-30 08:05:00'): '0.03059', Timestamp('2020-11-30 08:10:00'): '0.03061', Timestamp('2020-11-30 08:15:00'): '0.03074', Timestamp('2020-11-30 08:20:00'): '0.03062', Timestamp('2020-11-30 08:25:00'): '0.03052', Timestamp('2020-11-30 08:30:00'): '0.03066', Timestamp('2020-11-30 08:35:00'): '0.03064', Timestamp('2020-11-30 08:40:00'): '0.03064', Timestamp('2020-11-30 08:45:00'): '0.03068', Timestamp('2020-11-30 08:50:00'): '0.03072', Timestamp('2020-11-30 08:55:00'): '0.03065', Timestamp('2020-11-30 09:00:00'): '0.03058', Timestamp('2020-11-30 09:05:00'): '0.03043', Timestamp('2020-11-30 09:10:00'): '0.03050', Timestamp('2020-11-30 09:15:00'): '0.03058', Timestamp('2020-11-30 09:20:00'): '0.03048', Timestamp('2020-11-30 09:25:00'): '0.03045', Timestamp('2020-11-30 09:30:00'): '0.03037', Timestamp('2020-11-30 09:35:00'): '0.03034', Timestamp('2020-11-30 09:40:00'): '0.03045', Timestamp('2020-11-30 09:45:00'): '0.03048', Timestamp('2020-11-30 09:50:00'): '0.03054', Timestamp('2020-11-30 09:55:00'): '0.03056', Timestamp('2020-11-30 10:00:00'): '0.03064', Timestamp('2020-11-30 10:05:00'): '0.03062', Timestamp('2020-11-30 10:10:00'): '0.03067', Timestamp('2020-11-30 10:15:00'): '0.03075', Timestamp('2020-11-30 10:20:00'): '0.03073', Timestamp('2020-11-30 10:25:00'): '0.03064', Timestamp('2020-11-30 10:30:00'): '0.03063'})
df=df.astype(float)
hi = df.dropna().copy() 
lo = df.dropna().copy()  
for i in range(2):
    hi = hi.iloc[argrelmax(hi.values)[0]]
    lo = lo.iloc[argrelmin(lo.values)[0]] 
    hi = hi[~hi.index.isin(lo.index)]
    lo = lo[~lo.index.isin(hi.index)] 

hig=pd.concat([hi.astype(float)tail(3)])
highs = pd.DataFrame({'Date':hig.index, 'Highs':hig.values})
highs=highs.set_index('Date')
       
los=pd.concat([lo.astype(float).tail(3)]) 
lows=pd.DataFrame({'Date':los.index, 'Lows':los.values})
lows=lows.set_index('Date')
print(lows)
print(highs)
```

Which outputs:

```
                        Lows
Date                        
2020-11-30 04:45:00  0.03100
2020-11-30 06:25:00  0.03097
2020-11-30 09:35:00  0.03034
                       Highs
Date                        
2020-11-30 06:15:00  0.03117
2020-11-30 07:25:00  0.03133
2020-11-30 08:50:00  0.03072
```

Here I've dropped the indexes that appear in both Series with `.index.isin()`. However there are two highs appearing sequentially without a Low between. How do I drop every index that is not followed/preceded by an index from the other Series?

Expected output:

```
                        Lows
Date                        
2020-11-30 04:45:00  0.03100
2020-11-30 06:25:00  0.03097
2020-11-30 09:35:00  0.03034
                       Highs
Date
2020-11-30 01:10:00  0.03147                        
2020-11-30 06:15:00  0.03117
2020-11-30 07:25:00  0.03133
```

Added picture of output:
[image]

Added picture of plot with problem visible:
[image]

Comment: I added a sample series, was that the reason for the downvote? I was just looking for a pandas function or trick that could achieve the "every other index problem"

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Appreciate it

Comment: Damnit sorry I messed up the dict, it should recreate the problem as shown now.
2. Yes Argelmax/min returns many highs and lows but I only need the three latest for my purpose. 3. I agree they should, but they don't always do. I'm trying to find the pivot points in my data, I know it gets tricky when removing one high/low because then would have to determine which one is the "true" pivot point, but I thought i would figure that out once I learn a method for filtering the series so that every index is followed by an index in the other series

Comment: Your expected output still does not match the logic you claimed. The 3 latest local maxima (highs) are located at `09:15`, `10:00` and `10:15`. This can be easily seen directly by `df.plot()`. (`df = pd.to_numeric(df)` preprocessing is also required because you pasted the values as `str` instead of `float`).

Comment: Thats weird, I added a picture of the output when i copypasted above code, maybe you meant to `ax=plt.subplot() ax.plot(df) ax.plot(highs) ax.plot(lows) plt.show()`

Comment: I mean "the logic" is problematic, not a mismatch of output. `df.plot()` [yielded this](https://i.imgur.com/paAJucB.png), which indicates the locations of the last 3 local maxima by direct observation. BTW, I give up on this problem and won't discuss any more.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, are you saying I should just write code that better captures the real pivotpoints? I've been trying but at the moment this is the best I can do, however I'm always open to ideas!

Comment: Voted to close due to lack of clarity, and the problem also seems to be unsalvageable through editing. The OP fails to explain how the expected highs and lows (orange lines and greens lines) are defined. The sample code and logical descriptions ("argrelmax", "last 3", etc) did not relate to the results\.

Comment: Lack of clarity? My code gives you the highs and lows of a series, I'm just trying to find a way to remove values which index does not have an index from the other series preceding it. What more information do you want?